# Golang, Heroku - How to check if request is https

Tags: heroku, go

Documentation suggests you can check TLS on the request object, but that appears to be nil (on heroku at least).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers), it appears that HTTPS is terminated upstream of your application.

Check the request's `Headers` for a `X-Forwarded-Proto` header with the value `https`.